# element appearing in different places in different pages

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a>` in my project which redirects to the index page. In one page I have it included just after a table ends, and it appears below the table fine (like I want it to). But I have another page where I include it after a form ends but it appears right at the very top of the page. I have tried to tinker around with the css, the format of the html and used "inspect element" to try and understand why it is happening but I'm lost.

The page where it appears fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Players</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
          <header>
            <h1>Players</h1>
          </header>
          <div class="wrapper">
    
            <a href="add-player.php"> <h2 id="add">Add a new player!</h2> </a>
    
            <table border="0" cellspacing="30px" align="center">
              <tr>
                <th>Player ID</th>
                <th>Player Name</th>
                <th>Player Age</th>
                <th>Player Nation</th>
                <th>Player Team</th>
                <th>Team ID</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
              <?php foreach ($results as $r): ?>
              <tr style="text-align: center" class="row">
                <td><?php echo $r['playerID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['playerName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['playerAge']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['playerNation']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['playerTeam'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['teamID'] ?></td>
                <td><div class="action"> <a id="del" href="delete-player.php?id=<?=$r['playerID']?>">Delete</a> <hr> <a id="update" href="update-player.php?id=<?=$r['playerID']?>">Update</a></div></td>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
    
            <?php include('home.php'); ?>
    
          </div>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Page where it is wrong

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Football Database</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
         <div class="wrapper">
            <form class="add" action="" method="post">
              <label>Player Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_name" required><br>
    
              <label>Player Age</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_age" required><br>
    
              <label>Player Nation</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_nation" required><br>
    
              <label>Player Team</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_team" required><br>
    
              <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
    
            <?php include('home.php'); ?>
    
          </div>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
  html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../resources/img/football.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

form.add {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid navy;
  padding: 100px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px black;
}

form.add label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form.add input {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form.add input#submit {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form.add input#submit:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.wrapper a h2#add {
  text-align: center;
  color: #386ec4;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.3px #fff;
}

.action a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.action a#update {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.action a#del {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  color: grey;
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

/* Classes and ID's */

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.btn:active {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#btn1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#btn2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#btn3 {
  background-color: green;
}

#btn4 {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please consider the advice given on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please add your css. I am suspecting you have a float that doesnt cleared

Comment: @necilAlbayrak added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using absolute positioning on your form. If you turn that into relative problem will be solved. I believe you do that to center your form on the page you can achieve same result by using following css:

```
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto; //centers horizontionally;
margin-top: 30%; // same margin before;
max-width: 500px; //I also suggest limiting max width of form so if your inputs are not limited this will limit them
```